# odds of winning a raffle with multiple prizes.

Tags: probability

so i am struggling to get a formula to work out the odds for a raffle, there are actually 2 different instances so I will explain below:

Raffle 1: 500 tickets, 6 prizes to be won. Anyone can buy as many tickets as they like, however each time a prize is won the ticket goes back into the pot and can be won again. So, my question is if you buy one ticket then what are the odds or the probablilty of winning ONE of the SIX prizes? I think I am overcomplicating and second guessing my workings but I just want to be sure I am correct.

Raffle 2: much more complicated in my eyes and I will try my best to explain - This raffle has 999 tickets, a lottery ball machine is used and one winning ticket is chosen which is the jackpot prize (I understand odds to be 1/999). However, the winning jackpot number is added back to the machine and a runner up draw takes place and this is where it gets complicated because the lottery machine has 3 seperate chambers with numbers 0-9 in each, (jackpot winner is chosedn by teh winning number being the number across teh chambers, eg winning ticket is number 123 so teh winner would have chamber 1 draw ball number, chamber2 ball number 2 and chamber 3 ball number 3 so there can only be one winner). The runner up pot winners are those that match their number in any order, so as per example above ticket 123 would also come in 6 different outcomes so 6 winners, if someone had a ticket number with only 2 different numbers (889 for example) then there is 3 possible outcomes and therefor 3 winners, and someone with ticket 111, 222 etc is teh only winner and takes the entire pot. If you are still following me then what I am trying to work out is what is the overall odds of winning a runner up prize depending on if you have 1, 2 or 3 number combination? What are the overall odds if you include the jackpot too?

Assume all tickets are sold in both questions. Thanks very much in advance to anyone who can shed further light on this!

Comment: why don't you post the original questions instead of their subjective explanation?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. There isn't an original question, this is me asking the question...